# Unable to delete software log file

Tags: terminal

Apologies this must be a frequent question: I'm unable to delete the Betternet VPN log files after removing the app itself.
I first entered `sudo mdfind -name Betternet` to find all the relevant files for Betternet VPN and the results are

```
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.betternet.macos/Data/Library/gpr-com.betternet.macos-events.plist
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.betternet.macos/Data/Library/gpr-com.betternet.macos-properties.plist
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.betternet.macos/Data/Library/gpr-com.betternet.macos-event_bindings.plist
/Users/username/Library/Group Containers/36LJG4MA4Y.com.betternet.macos/Logs/com.betternet.macos.hydra-extension 2021-07-01--00-26-27-537.log
/Users/username/Library/Group Containers/36LJG4MA4Y.com.betternet.macos/Logs/com.betternet.macos.hydra-extension 2021-06-28--22-31-52-721.log
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.betternet.macos.hydra-extension/Data/Library/Application Support/com.betternet.macos.hydra-extension
/Users/username/Library/Application Scripts/com.betternet.macos.hydra-extension
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.betternet.macos/Data/Library/Application Support/com.betternet.macos
/Users/username/Library/Application Scripts/com.betternet.macos
```

and I tried `sudo rm -rf /filepath` and check to find out all files remain.

ps. Hope I'm wrong, but hydra-extension doesn't sound too good

Comment: You can try this command : 1) you verify : `find /Users/username -name "*betternet*"` 2) if the result is good, you can delete with : `find /Users/username -name "*betternet*" -exec rm -rf {} +`

Comment: Thank you problem solved following your command lines!

Comment: I'm glad for you ;-)